# how to send an email when create a new product in magento

Tags: magento, email

I'm new in Magento and I need to send an email to a specific admin when another admin creates a new product in Magento.

Please, how can I implement it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1. Add an event to your modules config.xml in global-tag or maybe better adminhtml-tag

   ```
   ...
   <events>
        <catalog_product_save_after>
           <observers>
               <yourmodule>
                   <type>singleton</type>
                   <class>yourmodule/observer</class>
                   <method>sendTransactionalMail</method>
               </yourmodule>
           </observers>
       </catalog_product_save_after>    
   </events>
   ```
2. In your observer class yourmodule/observer  which is in fact Your_Module_Model_Observer
   just send the transactional mail:

   ```
   public function sendTransactionalMail(){

   $senderName = 'NAME';
   $senderEmail = 'your@email.com';
   $sender = array('name' => $senderName,'email' => $senderEmail);
   $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
   $vars = array('subject' =>  'Product Save Notification');
   $transactionalEmail= Mage::getModel('core/email_template')->setDesignConfig(array('area'=>'frontend', 'store'=>$storeId));
   //create a new template via adminhtml and grab the id
   $emailTemplateId   = 17;
   $transactionalEmail->sendTransactional($emailTemplateId, $sender, $recepientEmail, "Admin", $vars); 
   }
   ```

Comment: You may need to add additional logic to check to see if it is a newly created product or just an edit. In your observer you could check for $product->getOrigData(xxx) ... see http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-event-observer-with-save-before-and-save-after/

Comment: Thanks!! It' worked... I created a new module and created an observer!!

Answer (score 0):

I would create an observer for the catalog_product_new_action event or maybe catalog_product_prepare_save event and then send the transactional.

Create observer tutorial:
http://www.pierrefay.com/event-observers-magento-tutorial-howto-105

Send transactional tutorial:
http://www.excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-sending-custom-emails